# Change For Each to Apply or Map

Tags: r

I'm using:

```
Type1<-matrix(ncol=1,nrow=nrow(OrdersWide2))
for (i in 1:nrow(OrdersWide2)){
  Type1[i,]<-detect(OrdersWide2[i,2:ncol(OrdersWide2)], function(x) x != "", .right = F)
}
Type1<-as.data.frame(Type1)
colnames(Type1)<-"Type1"
Orders3<-cbind(OrdersWide2,Type1)
```

In order to extract the primary shipping method from a list of orders (>650K rows).

How can I change this to use `Apply` or `Map`
I tried using:

`First<-function(x) detect(OrdersWide2[x,2:ncol(OrdersWide2)], function(y) y != "", .right = F)`

`Type1Test<-apply(OrdersWide2[1:5,],1,FUN = First)`

But keep getting `NULL`. Alternatively, is there a better method to get the first instance of `!=""` across columns for each row?

Sample Data:

```
OrdersWide2<-structure(list(Sales.Doc. = c("0001748328", "0001920412", "0020189342", 
"0020189350", "0020189353", "0020189354"), `47-Will Call` = c("47-Will Call", 
"47-Will Call", NA, NA, NA, NA), `48-LTL` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), `49-FTL` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `50-Sea Freight` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), `51-Air Freight` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `52-FedEx 1Day Freight` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), `53-FedEx 2Day Freight` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    `54-FedEx 3Day Freight` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), `55-FedEx Intl. Priority` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), `56-FedEx Intl. Economy` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), `57-FedEx Intl. Pri. Frt` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), `60-FedEx Ground Guarant` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), `64-DHL Global Forward` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), `65-Courier Services` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), `70-Purolator Ground` = c(NA, NA, "70-Purolator Ground", 
    "70-Purolator Ground", "70-Purolator Ground", "70-Purolator Ground"
    ), `71-QRC Logistics` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `72-Purolator Express` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `73-Purolator Exp 9:00AM` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `74-Purolator Exp10:30AM` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `90-BOMI` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    )), .Names = c("Sales.Doc.", "47-Will Call", "48-LTL", "49-FTL", 
"50-Sea Freight", "51-Air Freight", "52-FedEx 1Day Freight", 
"53-FedEx 2Day Freight", "54-FedEx 3Day Freight", "55-FedEx Intl. Priority", 
"56-FedEx Intl. Economy", "57-FedEx Intl. Pri. Frt", "60-FedEx Ground Guarant", 
"64-DHL Global Forward", "65-Courier Services", "70-Purolator Ground", 
"71-QRC Logistics", "72-Purolator Express", "73-Purolator Exp 9:00AM", 
"74-Purolator Exp10:30AM", "90-BOMI"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: IF you're trying to use functional syntax it's better to go straight to purr, its map function is much more intuitive: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.2.2

Comment: I thought it would be. My challenge is i'm not sure I understand `map()` enough to get `detect(OrdersWide2[x,2:ncol(OrdersWide2)], function(y) y != "", .right = F)` to run by row, efficiently. To add: I'm getting stuck on wrapping `detect` in another function.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what it is you are trying to extract. E.g. desired output from the sample input you gave.

Comment: Sure, if I run the `Type 1` For loop, it should output: `47-Will Call`, `47-Will Call`, NA, NA, NA, NA. Based on the sample data. The sample data didn't include other examples where, other columns may be filled. Full data has ~45 cols. I.e. the first result from Left to Right from each row.

Comment: So you want to return columns that contain something else than NA?

Comment: BTW using the for loop you provided and the example returns a column of NAs.

Comment: Edited sample data, output should be `47-Will Call` (2x) & `70-Purolator Ground` (4x)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161307/discussion-between-gregdelima-and-bar).